# placesautocomplete result code = 2

Tags: android, google-places-api, onactivityresult

I am trying to implement google Places APIs (Places Autocomplete) by creating an intent through intentBuilder. My app is successfully getting an intent with a button click but unable to search a place.

On overriding onActivityResult, it's getting resultCode = 2 instead of RESULT_SUCCESS, RESULT_ERROR or RESULT_CANCELLED and gets back to MainActivity.

I took reference from https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete
and added a dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getAddress());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("message", "the user cancelled the operation" );            }
    }
}
```

I need some assistance, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code is correct, it looks like there might be some error in your API_KEY. 
Please recheck the API_KEY, whether the correct SHA-1 fingerprint was used to generate the API_KEY, also don't forget to check whether you have enabled places API from the developer's console for the project. If all these are correct and you continue to face the same error, please send me the logs.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just check your Manifest file once,maybe you are trying this thing wrong...

instead of this Tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_key"/>
```

add this Tag:

```
<meta-data            
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_key" />
```

Hope this serve your purpose !!

Comment: Actually I am doing this without using map. How could i achieve this, is this possible or not??

Comment: while implementing it with google map, the same meta data which you have recommended has already been written there 

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

But I am still getting the same problem. Please help.

Comment: Check out the link i have pasted, in that full source code is available for Google places autocomplete..

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after a while-

Problem - onActivityResult in returns resultCode 2

Solution - 
1. This is solved by Enabling "Places API for Android" and not just "Places API" in the Developer Console.

2. This also happens if you have a wrong API key

Answer (score 0):

For me enabling Places API (New) as well as Places API was required. Check the logcat log for possible extra information.